# Getting the mapped column name through the mapped table (Sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have many databases that uses various column-names for the same things. For example, 'a1' in one table and 'a11' in other table and so on. Those tables are mapped through the secondary table. This means, as far as I know, for example, 'a' might be used to map both 'a1' and 'a2' Since I am not proficient with sql, I don't know how the actual mapping is done in the secondary (or main) table. My question is: Is there a direct way to know, by writing query to the mapped table( secondary table), the other column-name which are mapped to that column?

Comment: Are you asking "How do I know which fields to use in my JOINs" due to the fact that there is no consistent naming convention?

Comment: My question is basically: How can I retrieve the name of the fields through the table which is already mapped to various fields. For eg., I know table 1 is has a field name 'a' which is mapped to 'a1', 'a2'...and so on. I don't know THOSE 'a1','a2'....and so on. I want to write a query which gives me those field names to which 'a' is mapped to.

Comment: You can check for foreign keys.  But they might not be there.  That depends on the builder of the tables.  Also, the way to do this varies across sql products.  You've tagged this as three very different products, which are you using?

Comment: I am using MS-SQL server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `AS` will help you. It is used to map columns to a name you provide.

```
SELECT a1 AS first_a, a2 AS second_a FROM your_table;
```

[Read more…](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlas.php)